# How to configure GRUB for triple boot: Ubuntu 12.10, Windows 7 and RHEL Server 6.3

Tags: dual-boot

I just purchased a new Sony VAIO laptop so I can play around with Linux during the day while pretending to do my job. Ideally I'd like to be able to run Windows 7, Ubuntu and Red Hat on this machine … at the very least.

I’ve divided my 256GB SSD into four partitions:

1. 500MB boot drive
2. 50GB partition for Windows 7
3. 43GB partition for future use
4. 157GB extended partition subdivided into two physical volumes (one for Red Hat and one for Ubuntu)

I've created a volume group named `vg_rh` for the Red Hat physical volume and a volume group named `vg_ubuntu` for the Ubuntu physical volume.

I've installed Red Hat on three logical volumes within the `vg_rh` group:

1. lv_rh_root (/)
2. lv_rh_home (/home)
3. lv_rh_swap

The Red Hat boot drive (`/boot`) is mounted on the first primary partition above.

I've similarly installed Ubuntu on four logical volumes within the `vg_ubuntu` group:

1. lv_ub_root
2. lv_ub_home
3. lv_ub_swap
4. lv_ub_boot

I’m not sure if this was really such a great way to organize everything, but so far I’ve been able to boot into Red Hat and Windows just fine from the GRUB version 0.97 menu.  However I’m having a hard time figuring out how to add Ubuntu to the list of operating systems in the GRUB menu.

Here are the contents of the grub.conf file:

```
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64)
       root (hd0,0)
       kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_rh-lv_rh_root nomodeset rd_LVM_LV=vg_ubuntu/lv_ub_swap KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd NO_LUKS SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M rd_LVM_LV=vg_rh/lv_rh_swap rd_MD_UUID=a0bdf209:5c03cb84:36ee492f:a8dbd731 rd_LVM_LV=vg_rh/lv_rh_root rd_MD_UUID=795f29cc:0b48c395:98447868:144877f2 rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
       initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.img

title Windows 7
       rootnoverify (hd0,1)
       chainloader +1

title Ubuntu 12.10
       root (hd0,0)
       kernel /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_ubuntu-lv_ub_root rhgb quiet
       initrd /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

> title Ubuntu 12.10  
>   root (hd0,0)  
>          kernel **/boot**/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_ubuntu-lv_ub_root rhgb quiet  
>          initrd **/boot**/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

Please try to add /boot behind the kernel and initrd. I had the same problem with SL 6.4 and Mint 13 and found out that my kernel name in grub.cfg had an error at the end in the kernel filename inside /boot.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

See my triple boot, using three different hard disks.

The cool thing is, it requires no modifications of the Master Boot Record.

http://rodgersnotes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/rodgers-very-simple-dual-boot-method/
http://rodgersnotes.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/secrets-of-bios-grub-and-triple-boot-servers/

HTH